# Move database from elastic pool to single database in Azure

Tags: database, azure

I believe I'm getting charged the elastic pool rates for a database in Azure instead of the single database rate (something like 16 times as much). How can I change the database to single database and change the payment plan?

Comment: Did you look in the portal blade at the various settings?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to move the database out of an elastic pool.

For detailed instructions on how you can do it on Azure Portal, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool-manage-portal#move-a-database-out-of-an-elastic-pool.

Also, from your question it seems that you only have one database in the pool. If that's the case, after you move your database out of the pool you can simply delete that pool.